# Exchange Web Services Managed API: is it possible to have an Item other than EmailMessage in the mail folder?

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are using the latest version of EWS Managed API and I'd like to know if it is possible to get an Item in the Inbox of type any other than `EmailMessage`or it's descendants (like `MeetingRequest`, `MeetingCancellation` etc?
I could not find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, assuming you have an item of that type in the inbox. For example, using Outlook, you can create a new Post in your Inbox. That would be a PostItem in the Managed API.

Comment: Thank you. And do you know if there are any other similar items? I could not find a way to create a Post in the Inbox folder from Office 365 web client, so would like to check something else which can be used in Office 365.

Comment: An item of any type could theoretically appear in the Inbox. Using Outlook you can drag items into the Inbox from another folder. Outlook Web App is a little more restrictive, and it doesn't seem to give you as much freedom in moving things to folders that weren't designed to hold that type.